# Google Bookmark Plugin for Firefox

Tags: firefox, plugins, bookmarks

I'm having a real hard time looking for the right Firefox plugin regarding Google Bookmarks.

I tried Deng, GMarks, Fess, and all the other popular ones but I still cant bookmark my links.  I seriously consider Google Bookmarks as the ultimate bookmarking tool and I've been 'google-bookmarking' ever since its very existence, in other words, I've been doing that for a very long time; at first, I used to bookmark manually and then GMarks has been working fine for a few years.

I just want a Firefox Plugin that works, one that works !!!! for Google Bookmarks; I explore possibilities of other plugins that work for a certain period of time and I have to try another one.

I have a 64-Bit Windows 7 OS with 2GB of RAM

Hope someone helps me here, thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found it? I can't find one (that is actually able to add a new bookmark) either.

Comment: this is really weird, i mean that plugin is essential and was the only reason why i was using firefox; that made firefox the ideal plugin for a coder, a designer, in fact anyone; 

and i have been asking that for nearly a year so surely the others are either not bookmarking at all or have found another way that i clearly am not aware of

Comment: Try searching superuser.com. If the answer is not there, you should ask there.

Comment: thanks still_dreaming_1, so we're only 3-4 coming across this problem, how does everyone else do it loll !? well, 2 years gone by and still the 'best' google bookmark plugin for firefox remains fess bookmark manager, with its basic functionalities; does the job, few adjustments here and there